# view.getText().toString() returning nothing from DialogFragment?

Tags: android

I have a Custom DialogFragment class. The user types their password twice in 2 editText views. When I Log the action I get an empty text from both editTexts even though I typed some text in them both:

> D/CreateNewWalletDialogFragment: password:  password repeat:

```
public class CreateNewWalletDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    CreateNewWalletDialogListener createNewWalletDialogListener;

    @BindView(R.id.password_edit)
    TextView password;
    @BindView(R.id.password_edit_repeat)
    TextView password_repeat;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try{
            createNewWalletDialogListener = (CreateNewWalletDialogListener) context;
        }catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        ButterKnife.bind(this, View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.create_wallet_popup, null));
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_wallet_popup, null))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.create_wallet_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        String password_s = password.getText().toString();
                        String password_repeat_s = password_repeat.getText().toString();
                        Timber.d("password: "+password_s+" password repeat: "+ password_repeat_s);

                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

As suggested by someone, binding views in `onStart()` method did not help me either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem lies here:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this, View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.create_wallet_popup, null));
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_wallet_popup, null))
```

noticed as you have two `inflate`s? Inflates returns a new instance everytime it gets call, so, in your case, the view you are prompting on the screen is different from the one ButterKnife binds. Try with

```
 View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.create_wallet_popup, null);
 ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
 builder.setView(view)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is correct. It makes sense now. Will accept answer when timelimit allows me to. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be EditText, not TextView.

Try this

```
@BindView(R.id.password_edit)
EditText password;
@BindView(R.id.password_edit_repeat)
EditText password_repeat;
```

Comment: `EditText` is a subclass of `TextView`

Comment: It should work anyways, because of what @Blackbelt said. But Maybe in my case, I should change it to EditText. Thanks for the suggestion.